# __proto__ поможет уменьшить затраты памяти?

Tags: javascript

Я имею в виду, отличаются ли затраты памяти на:

```
var obj = {
    a:"b",
    c:"d"
};
var temp = obj;
```

От:

```
temp.__proto__ = obj;
```

Comment: Вы разберитесь для начала что делает `__proto__` и от куда он взялся, потом вы поймёте почему ваш код не имеет смысла.

Comment: Первое - простое присвоение ссылки, второе - то же присвоение, только для источника прототипа. `__proto__` - ссылка на прототип, используется для одной из крутейших фишек JS.